# One webpage that uses lots of ram but one apache connection vs one small ram connection with several ajax calls. Which is better?

Tags: ajax, apache, web

If this is the not the right place to ask this please direct me to the correct place.

My question is this. Which is better:

A. a page that uses a lot of resources and a lot of RAM, but only one Apache connection.

B. that same page, loaded from cache, with several ajax calls to populate the parts of it that need live data.

I'm thinking B. The only negative to B is that i'm adding 4-5 Apache connections per page load. But these connections are super small resource wise.

Thanks

Comment: Define "better"...  What is better in your sense.  Quickest overall page load time?  Quickest perceived page load time (i.e. stuff gets loaded in background asynchronously)?  Which one is easier to scale on the server?  Your question is impossible to answer as you have not defined the criteria for what is most important to you.

Comment: Better is less load on the server

Answer (score 0):

This is broad and open-based, so it will likely be closed. The answer depends a lot on what type of page you are serving and what experience you want the user to have. Both options will use a lot of resources in a short period of time, although option B may be easier to load-balance. The downside is that option B also uses a lot more connections, resulting in slower load and render times, not to mention a little more load on Apache itself.

Comment: Where is the place to discuss this? I don't see how B uses a lot of resource.. it uses 0 connections to load the page, as it's loaded out of browser cache - or server cache if this is your first load - both set for a 10 min cache. So only once every 10 min does the server have do work to render the page. The rest of the time, it loads the page from cache then fires out 4 small ajax requests. tiny tiny Ram useage. stuff like "how many items are in the cart" etc..

Comment: Also we ARE moving to load balancing sometime this year.. so if it's easier to load balance.. then i'm moving in the right direction..

Comment: Sorry 3 comments, but i don't see it render slower either.. the entire cache pages renders right away.. the ajax calls just insert html to the already rendered page..

Comment: It still hits the server for the same information, just broken into chunks. How you load the page doesn't necessarily have much to do with what you can, can't, should, or shouldn't cache. If something imposes a high server load, doing it in five steps instead of one just spreads the load out over time.

Comment: Re your third comment: the point isn't how long the browser takes to render received data. The point is that `request -> receive -> render` becomes `request -> receive -> render -> request AJAX data -> receive AJAX data -> render AJAX data`, which is much slower, even if the first part is cached.

Comment: Well my thought is it allows me to cache most of the page.. that without a cache, would have to render via it's templates and database calls to data etc.. stuff that i don't mind being 10 min behind real time. But stuff that needs to be real time.. i use the ajax calls for. So it lets me cache what i want and not cache what i don't want. Thus breaking up the load, into 2 parts.. one part that runs 1 time every 10 min. (that's 1 time.. not 1 time per user) and parts that run every call.

Comment: Just cache things server-side regardless. Your rendering engine may already handle this. If not, it should. But regardless, the issue isn't breaking it into multiple requests; it's doing better caching server-side so that the rendering of things that change rarely isn't high-load, period.